# How to save selections from a multi-select listbox using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to Entify Framework so this is probably a very basic question.  In a WinForms application I have a data entry page that works fine until I add a listbox and try to update the database with the selections that have been made.

On the form the user selects a file to upload and specifies one or more departments that can access the file.  Here's how I thought it would work:

```
using (var ctx = new FCEntities())
{
  var batch = new Batch() { Description = txtDescription.Text, Filename = filename, Departments = (System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Department>)lstDepartments.SelectedItems };
  ctx.AddToBatches(batch);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

But when this didn't work I did some research and learned that I can't cast the SelectedItems to EntityCollection so I decided to copy the items from the original collection into a new collection and then use the new collection as follows:

```
using (var ctx = new FCEntities())
{
  var departments = new System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Department>();

  foreach (var department in lstDepartments.SelectedItems)
  {
    departments.Add((Department)department);
  }

  var batch = new Batch() {Description = txtDescription.Text, Filename = filename, Departments=departments };
  ctx.AddToBatches(batch);
      ctx.SaveChanges();
```

}

This didn't work either and gave this error on the **departments.Add** line:

> "An object that is attached to an ObjectContext cannot be added to an
>   EntityCollection or EntityReference that is not associated with a
>   source object."

I don't understand because it doesn't appear to me that the department object is attached to the ObjectContext?  I'm obviously missing something fundamental, so any advice and/or links to examples of how others do this would be appreciated.

Comment: I barely use EF plus I don't quite get your model yet but isn't it so that you mix different contexts? You somehow read the items, put them in the list and here, in the code from snippet above, you create yet another context and try to use these items from the list. Maybe this is why EF is happy about it. However, since I am not sure if this is the case, I am not posting this as an answer.

Comment: @Wiktor, I'm not sure what you mean.  I only create a single context.

Comment: @DarvisLombardo: yes, there is a single context on the snippet above. But HOW AND WHERE you add items to the listbox and what context do you use then? The same as above? I doubt so, as the one above is disoosed just after use. Can you verify this?

Comment: @Wiktor: yeah, I see what you are saying.  In the form load I create a context, run a query, and set that as the DataSource for the listbox.  Is that what you were referring to as the second context?

Comment: Yes, this way you mix different contexts and this probably hurts the EF.

Comment: @Wiktor:  Thanks for your comments.  As you can see from the answer I posted below, you got me started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to leave an answer to this in case someone else runs into this someday.  The comments left by Wiktor were helpful in getting me in the right direction.  I decided I had a lack of fundamental understanding so I did some reading on MSDN and was able to resolve my issue.

The datamodel behind this existed of three tables:  Batches, Departments, and Batches_Departments which allowed for a many to many relationship between Batches and Departments.

The problem with my original code/logic, in a nutshell, was that the Department objects in the ListBox were associated with a different context than the one I was using in my Save method.  EF didn't like this for obvious reasons (at least now they are obvious), so in the save method I used the ID from the selected Departments to get a reference to the same Department in the current context.  I could then add this Department to the newly created batch.

Here's what the code now looks like:

```
using (var ctx = new FCEntities())
{
  var batch = new Batch() { Description = txtDescription.Text, Filename = filename};

  foreach (var department in lstDepartments.CheckedItems)
  {
    var dept = (from d in ctx.Departments where d.DepartmentID == ((Department)department).DepartmentID select d).First();
    batch.Departments.Add(dept);
  }

  ctx.Batches.AddObject(batch);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who is dealing with the same issue.